# attribute value using msxml from xml

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
- <DEVICEMESSAGES>
  <VERSION xml="1" checksum="" revision="0" envision="33050000" device="" /> 
  <HEADER id1="0001" id2="0001" content="Nasher[<messageid>]: <!payload>" /> 
  <MESSAGE level="7" parse="1" parsedefvalue="1" tableid="15" id1="24682" id2="24682" eventcategory="1003010000" content="Access to <webpage> was blocked due to its category (<info> by <hostname>)" /> 
  </DEVICEMESSAGES>
```

I am using the following xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method="text"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:template match="DEVICEMESSAGES">
       <xsl:value-of select="@id2"/>,<xsl:text/>
       <xsl:value-of select="@content"/>,<xsl:text/>
       <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when i use MSXML i just get ,, whereas i want to have something like

```
id2,             content
0001 ,           Nasher[<messageid>]: <!payload>"
```

Comment: MSXML only supports XSLT V1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The `DEVICEMESSAGES` element doesn't have attributes at all**.

Change:

```
<xsl:template match="DEVICEMESSAGES">
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="DEVICEMESSAGES/HEADER">
```

Comment: Hi Dimitre

Thank you very much

Comment: Any ideas how do i add column headers to the output though ?

Comment: @edwards: Please, ask this in a separate, new question.